# Object sharing　between renderPrint and renderPlot

Tags: r, shiny

In the following example, the R object `fit` is created in `shiny::renderPrint` but not in `renderPlot`. Thus plot done for `print()` but not `plot()`. 
In actual phase, `fit` is an fitted model object generated by `rstan:sampling()` and it takes very long time, so I won't execute it twice in both  `renderPrint` and `renderPlot`. Is there any idea ? I am very beginner of Shiny.

```
    library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(  
         mainPanel(
            shiny::sliderInput("aaa",
                               "aaa:",
                               min = 1, max = 11111, value = 5),

            shiny::plotOutput("plot"),
            shiny::verbatimTextOutput("print")       )
    )


     server <- function(input, output) {
        output$print <- shiny::renderPrint({
            fit <- input$aaa*100 # First creation of object, 
                                 # and we use it in the renderPlot.
                                 # So, we have to create it twice even if it is exactly same??
                                 # If possible, I won't create it 
                                 # In the renderPlot, twice.
            print(fit)
        })



        output$plot <- shiny::renderPlot({

          # The fit is again created
          # If time to create fit is very long, then total time is very heavy.
          # If possible, I do not want to make fit again.

           fit <- input$aaa*100  #<- Redundant code or I want to remove it.

           plot(1:fit)
        })
    }

     shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

**Edit**

To avoid a duplicate code of making object, I use the following, then it goes well. Thank you @bretauv.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

    mainPanel(
        shiny::sliderInput("aaa",
                           "aaa:",
                           min = 1, max = 11111, value = 5),

        shiny::plotOutput("plot"),
        shiny::verbatimTextOutput("print")       )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

##########     Avoid duplicate process             ###################
    test <- reactive({input$aaa*100})
#####################################################################    


    output$print <- shiny::renderPrint({
      #  fit <- input$aaa*100  # No longer required 
        print(test())
    })



    output$plot <- shiny::renderPlot({
       # fit <- input$aaa*100  # No longer required 

        plot(1:test())
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: if you want not to repeat ```fit```, try to put the ```fit``` expression in a reactive function such as : ```test <- reactive({input$aaa*100})``` and then call it in ```output``` functions with ```test()```

Comment: Thank your for reply @bretauv, I will try it!!

Comment: I could do, thank you, @bretauv.

Comment: I put my comment as an answer, validate it then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want not to repeat `fit`, try to put the `fit` expression in a reactive function such as : `test <- reactive({input$aaa*100})` and then call it in `output` functions with `test()`